# Regex for strings with $ signs, commas and decimals in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

is it possible to have regex in Python that satisfies all the below STRING conditions?

```
1,000
1,000.00
$1,000.00
1000
-1000
```

I have the below but it doesn't satisfy all conditions:

```
if bool(re.compile(r"^\+?\-?\d*[.,]?\d*\%?$").match(text.strip())) == True:
   print ("Matched")
```

Comment: Did you try `r"^\+?\-?\d*[.,]?\d*\%?\$"`

Comment: It doesn't satisfy 1,700.00

Answer (score 0):

Try the pattern `(?:[$-])?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> text='''1,000
1,000.00
$1,000.00
1000
-1000'''

>>> re.findall('(?:[$-])?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?', text)
['1,000', '1,000.00', '$1,000.00', '1000', '-1000']
```

**Understanding the pattern:**

```py
(?:[$-])?     Matches zero/one $ or - at the beginning
\d+           Matches one or more digits
(?:,\d+)*     Matches zero or more occurrence of comma separated numbers
(?:\.\d+)?    Matches zero or one occurrence of number after decimal at last
```